# javascript "basic Object Oriented", callbacks, and headache with this, hopefully a good example

Tags: javascript

Please run the following example, it "bit me a while", as I'm no javascript expert, when trying to do things more object oriented with the "original javascript" (read large browser compatibility).

Can you please provide your experience in regard to the comment line, asking "what's better" -- meaning more clear, less error prone when writing javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
</style>
<script>
function makeI(myId, myA) { 
  var I = {
    id: myId,
    A: myA,

    toString: function toString() { console.log('id:' +I.id+ ', A=' +this.A); return this;},
    //                                                 ^              ^
    //                                                 |              |
    //             What's better, more clear?       shorter      how does this help, just fools us on callbacks?
    // 
    oops: function oops() {
      document.getElementById('div').onclick = function() 
        { console.log('oops() A=' +this.A+ '   , darn! Well, the id=' +this.id+ " , NOT our/I's id"); }
    },

    f: function f() {
      document.getElementById('div').onclick = function() 
        { console.log('oops() A=' +I.A+ '  , good. Well, the id=' +I.id); }
    },
  }
  return I;
}
function try1() {
  console.log('---- try1() , my oops ---------');
  var i1 = makeI('1', 10).toString();
  i1.oops();
  console.log('OK, now please click on gold div, and watch the error\n');
}
function try2() {
  console.log('---- try2() ---------');
  var i2 = makeI('2', 20).toString(); 
  i2.f();
  console.log('OK, now please click on gold div\n');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick='try1()' style='border: 2px solid   red; width:400px;'>Please click, and see console output (oops!)</div><br>
<div onclick='try2()' style='border: 2px solid green; width:400px;'>Please click, and see console output, comments please</div><br>
<div id='div' style='border: 2px solid  gold; width:400px;'>div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "large browser compatibility": classes are supported by chrome 49, edge 13, and firefox 45. Are you sure you need greater comparability?   (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Yes, I want to go back to 2009, so if someone has a 10 year old device, and don't update it, things will still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your version, `toString`, `oops`, and `f` are all *different* functions, bound to different instances of `I`. This is the only reason why `I.myId` works in your case. Generally, however, we prefer to have one function that is called with different values of `this` so that the engine has to do less work (creates fewer individual functions).

For clarity and ease of maintainability, [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are preferred, especially for Object-Oriented development.

```js
class I {
  constructor(myId, myA) {
    this.id = myId;
    this.A = myA;
  }
  
  toString() {
    // NOTE: It's bad practice to not return a string from `toString()`
    console.log('id:' + this.id + ', A=' + this.A);
    return this;
  }
  
  oops() {
    document.getElementById('div').onclick = () => {
      console.log('oops() A=' + this.A + '   , darn! Well, the id=' + this.id + " , NOT our/I's id");
    };
  }
  
  f() {
    document.getElementById('div').onclick = () => {
      console.log('oops() A=' + this.A + '  , good. Well, the id=' + this.id);
    };
  }
}

// NOTE: This function doesn't really do anything anymore; you can probably remove it
function makeI(myId, myA) {
  return new I(myId, myA);
}

function try1() {
  console.log('---- try1() , my oops ---------');
  var i1 = makeI('1', 10).toString();
  i1.oops();
  console.log('OK, now please click on gold div, and watch the errors\n');
}

function try2() {
  console.log('---- try2() ---------');
  var i2 = makeI('2', 20).toString();
  i2.f();
  console.log('OK, now please click on gold div\n');
}
```

```html
<div onclick='try1()' style='border: 2px solid   red; width:400px;'>Please click, and see console output (oops!)</div><br>
<div onclick='try2()' style='border: 2px solid green; width:400px;'>Please click, and see console output, comments please</div><br>
<div id='div' style='border: 2px solid  gold; width:400px;'>div</div>
```

If you really need to support older browsers, I'd recommend using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile the above code into backward compatible JavaScript. For example, When the above class is transpiled with `ie 6`, you'll get something like this:

```
"use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } }

function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }

var I =
/*#__PURE__*/
function () {
  function I(myId, myA) {
    _classCallCheck(this, I);

    this.id = myId;
    this.A = myA;
  }

  _createClass(I, [{
    key: "toString",
    value: function toString() {
      console.log('id:' + this.id + ', A=' + this.A);
      return this;
    }
  }, {
    key: "oops",
    value: function oops() {
      var _this = this;

      document.getElementById('div').onclick = function () {
        console.log('oops() A=' + _this.A + '   , darn! Well, the id=' + _this.id + " , NOT our/I's id");
      };
    }
  }, {
    key: "f",
    value: function f() {
      var _this2 = this;

      document.getElementById('div').onclick = function () {
        console.log('oops() A=' + _this2.A + '  , good. Well, the id=' + _this2.id);
      };
    }
  }]);

  return I;
}();
```

Comment: Thanks @p.s.w.g, I'm looking at your answer.  Regarding older browser support, I only want to go back 10 years or till 2009, so this Javascript is fine, right?  ... or is Babel still good to use, and why?

Comment: @Ray IE 11 was released October 17, 2013 (almost 6 years ago at the time of writing). As of today it still holds about [2.6% market share](https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php). Whether you need to use Babel will depend on your exact needs and your user base (for example, I suspect stack overflow has a much lower proportion of IE11 users than say MSN).

Comment: I see, constructor is the newer Javascript, I'm not sure if ES 2015, or ES6.  But are you saying, write in the new version, and deliver in the older version running Babel on the code?  And if constructor is EC 2015, it doesn't go back that far, right?

Comment: Isn't constructor a ES 2015 or ES 6 release?

Comment: @Ray Yes, [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) was first standardized in ES6 (EcmaScript 2015), though ES6 is more or less supported by all major browsers except IE.

Comment: So then, can't the problem be, anything older than 2015?

Comment: @Ray The ES6 standard was officially published in 2015, but many browsers had begun supporting many of its key features long before then. Implementation of other features may have lagged behind a bit. In other words, the year a standard was published is not strictly related to when that standard adopted by browsers. For example, both Chrome and Firefox didn't natively support `constructor` syntax until March 2016.

Comment: I've got a major confusion still looking at your answer: in the "oops", arguably 'this' is valuable, it is a pointer back to the div.  So, what does one best do now, that 'this' no longer refers back to the div?  Also, so "you're really saying", if you want to support folks in the public with perhaps devices and no updates older than 2016, THEN YOU BETTER USE BABEL?

Comment: @Ray Or I guess what I'm really trying to say is, you can't always rely on browsers to support given features in the standard. This is precisely why Babel exists -- so you can code to the standard rather than to the browser. Also [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have slightly different rules for `this` that *usually* makes things a little bit simpler to understand when reading code. In this case `this` refers to the same thing as the outer function it's wrapped in.

Comment: So how does one readily get the pointer to the div?  What do you recommend for that, perhaps please show me setting its innerHTML contents ...

Comment: @Ray For that you'd use `const div = document.getElementById('div'); div.addEventListener('click', () => div.innerHTML = 'foo');`

Comment: Thanks @p.s.w.g, I appreciate your time and help.  And I have a huge gift for you ... go to AllWell dot world (in a couple weeks).  That's who you're helping, and you won't believe what you're going to get (you might just save it as an appt in your phone, or in 1 month).  I appreciate your help and time.